# Firestore Array Query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a dropdown where I want to filter based on the options were selected. How can I do this without chain a where for every single scenario a user selects. For example, a user may select for pick up and drop off but not shipping. PS this is a shorten version.

[image]

**Firebase Database snippets**

Option 1

[image]

Option 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the option from your dropdown as a field variable in the .where() clause when querying your database. Like when you choose "PickUp", you can save this value in variable:

```
const filterField = "PickUp";

db.collection("mycollection").where(filterField, "==", true);
```

for this to work, the documents should have either of these options as a field like:

```
doc1 {

PickUp: true

}
```